# Why am I getting this error in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is the error I am getting:

> Assets/Scripts/CameraScript.cs(60,39): error CS1612: Cannot modify a value type return value of `UnityEngine.Transform.position'. Consider storing the value in a temporary variable

This is my code:

```
void  Start (){
        thisTransform = transform;

        // Disable screen dimming
        Screen.sleepTimeout = 0;
    }

    void  Update (){
        //Reset playerscore 
        playerScore = settings.playerScore;

        //Smooth follow player character
        if  (target.position.y > thisTransform.position.y)  {           
            thisTransform.position.y = Mathf.SmoothDamp( thisTransform.position.y, 
                                                        target.position.y, ref velocity.y, smoothTime);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set the `thisTransform.position.y` value alone. Set the `thisTransform.position` instead.

For example:

```
if  (target.position.y > thisTransform.position.y)  {           
  thisTransform.position = new Vector3(thisTransform.position.x, 
                                       Mathf.SmoothDamp( thisTransform.position.y, target.position.y, ref velocity.y, smoothTime), 
                                       thisTransform.position.z);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`Transform.position.y` is read-only in C#, so in order to modify it you'll need to store the value of `Transform.position` to a temporary variable first, change the value from that variable, then assign it back to `Transform.position`:

```
Vector3 temp = thisTransform.position;
temp.y = Mathf.SmoothDamp( temp.y, target.position.y, ref velocity.y, smoothTime);
thisTransform.position = temp;
```